# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Class 'app\Project' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am following the course "Laravel 5.5 for beginners - Become a Master Developer". I am currently at the video "026 How to display has many relationships in Laravel".

My code is supposed to fetch the projects that belongs to the company, but I am getting this error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Class 'app\Project' not found
>   (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\pmanager\pmanager\resources\views\companies\show.blade.php)
>   Previous exceptions
>   Class 'app\Project' not found (0)

What's going wrong?

Model:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('app\Project');
}
```

Controller:

```
public function show(Company $company)
{
    // $company = Company::where('id', $company->id)->first();
    $company = Company::find($company->id);
    return view('companies.show', ['company' => $company]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel so silly.

the problem was that the name of the folder was suppose to be uppercase and i wrote lowercase:

--return $this->hasMany('app\Project');

++return $this->hasMany('App\Project');

Comment: Yup. Case sensitive matters, especially on Linux/Mac.